# What's this (undocumented?) call to GetFileAttributesW()?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

When I open `WinBase.inl`, I see:

```
ISOLATION_AWARE_INLINE FARPROC IsolationAwarePrivatenCv
IsolationAwarePrivatezltRgCebPnQQeRff(
    __in IsolationAwarePrivateCpBAFGnAG_zBqHyr_vAsB c,
    __inout IsolationAwarePrivateCzHGnoyr_zBqHyr_vAsB m,
    __in PCSTR ProcName
    )
{
    FARPROC Proc = NULL;
    HMODULE hModule;
#ifdef _M_IX86
    static HMODULE s_moduleUnicows;
    static BOOL s_fUnicowsInitialized;

    /*
       get unicows.dll loaded on-demand
    */
    if (!s_fUnicowsInitialized)
    {
    if ((GetVersion() & 0x80000000) != 0)
    {
        GetFileAttributesW(L"???.???");
        s_moduleUnicows = GetModuleHandleA("Unicows.dll");
    }
    s_fUnicowsInitialized = TRUE;
    }

    /*
       always call GetProcAddress(unicows) before the usual .dll
    */
    if (s_moduleUnicows != NULL)
    {
    Proc = GetProcAddress(s_moduleUnicows, ProcName);
    if (Proc != NULL)
        goto Exit;
    }
#endif
    hModule = m->WinbaseIsolationAwarePrivateybNQRQzbQhYR;
    if (hModule == NULL)
    {
#ifdef _M_IX86
    hModule = (((GetVersion() & 0x80000000) != 0) ? (*c->WinbaseIsolationAwarePrivateybNQn)(c->WinbaseIsolationAwarePrivateANZRn) : (*c->WinbaseIsolationAwarePrivateybNQJ)(c->WinbaseIsolationAwarePrivateANZRJ));
#else
    hModule = (*c->WinbaseIsolationAwarePrivateybNQJ)(c->WinbaseIsolationAwarePrivateANZRJ);
#endif
    if (hModule == NULL)
        goto Exit;
    m->WinbaseIsolationAwarePrivateybNQRQzbQhYR = hModule;
    }
    Proc = GetProcAddress(hModule, ProcName);
Exit:
    return Proc;
}
```

Does anyone know what `GetFileAttributesW(L"???.???");` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sort of not doing anything.  It's a dummy call with the sole purpose of forcing the DLL it lives in (`Unicows.dll`) to be loaded into memory so its handle can be retrieved.  The parameter is just a useless Unicode string "filename", since the actual value isn't wanted and it's a little faster if the call errors out on an illegal filename (no wildcards allowed) rather than hitting the disk just to throw the result out.

Comment: Ooooooooooooooh... it would've helped if I knew what `Unicows.dll` was lol. That makes a lot of sense, thanks.